# Where should I store login Data?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, authentication

I'm creating a small app that let the user enter his Google account Name and Password and show him available spreadsheets on his Google Drive Account.

I want to let the user the ability to save this following data:

1. true or false, if to connect to his account automaticaly.
2. Google Account Name(email)
3. Password

I want to do this, so he doesn't have to write them again when the program start.

What is the reccommended way to save this data on the user computer?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use the Google Drive APIs with OAuth 2.

Comment: If you're using Google's authentication, than you shouldn't store his login data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Application developers should never store user credentials. 
Please get an OAuth 2 key for your application from google, when the user logins to google account via your app for the first time. Store that key in your app securely.

[More details about google API's here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide#create_project)

Comment: so they will enter user name and password once, and i can get a uniqe token that will be created, and store it? cool didnt knew that i will try it out. but where sould i store this token?

Comment: I hope, you will find your required solution. Thanks @samy

Comment: thank you for the advice, i will take the path you suggested :)

Comment: @The Indian Prigrammer: can you please help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169695/match-data-from-two-tables-in-a-datagridview-c-sharp?noredirect=1 thanks