# match data from two tables in a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` containing a list of items which user can update. The items data come from `tblitems` which have a column `categoryId`. I have made a `combobox column` whose `value member` is `categoryId`(the same as in `tblitems`) and `display member` (the name of category) from the `tblcategories`.
Now, I want to populate data from `tblitems` and match the category id with the category id from `tblitems`. When I do that, it gives me a data mismatch error. How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code:

```
//conn.getDataTable is just a method to return datatable.
        category_id.DataSource = conn.getDataTable("Select category_id from tblcategories");
        category_id.DisplayMember = "category_id";
        category_id.ValueMember = "category_id";
        DataTable items = conn.getDataTable("Select itemname,itemprice,category_id from tblitem");
```

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: @AnuragJain, I have updated my question. can you check it please?